# How to map Shift+- (Shift+dash) in vim?

Tags: vim

I am struggling with binding Shift+- combination in vim. I have tried both options below to no available and googling does not bring any relevant information.

```
nnoremap <S-\-> <C-W>-
nnoremap <S--> <C-W>-
```

I am running Linux and want to bind `-` key which is between `0` and `=` keys.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? On a Mac or on Windows/Linux PC? What "minus" key are you talking about? The one on the top row or the one on the numpad?

Comment: I am on Linux. Laptop keyboard and I mean the dash next to `0` and `=` keys (first row).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the character on the key.

```
nnoremap _ <C-W>-
```

Comment: For a US keyboard; other keyboards might be different.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Neovim on Windows 10 was to go into insert mode, hit Ctrl-V and then key combination I wanted to map.

This revealed `<C-->` for ctrl-dash and `<C-S-_>` for ctrl-shift-dash